# Regex find contents between curly brackets across line break

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following string:

```
text="""foo: '{{ .Env.FOO
  }}'
bar: '{{ .Env.BAR }}'
foobar: {{ .Env.FOOBAR }}
"""
```

I can match the single-line cases easily enough with

```
import re
found=re.findall("{{ .Env..*?}}", text)
```

But how would I match the case where the }} is on the second line? I've tried the following but matches up to the final }} it finds. Something that stops at the first }} would work.

```
with_line_break=re.findall("{{ .Env..*?\n.*}}", text)
print(with_line_break)
```

Prints:

```
{{ .Env.FOO
  }}
{{ .Env.BAR }}'
foobar: {{ .Env.FOOBAR }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flag [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

> `re.DOTALL`
>
> Make the '`.`' special character match any character at all,
> including a newline; without this flag, '`.`' will match anything except
> a newline. Corresponds to the inline flag `(?s)`.

```
found = re.findall("{{ .Env..*?}}", text, re.DOTALL)
```